# Trying to delete image in firebase real time database in react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am trying to delete an image uploaded to the firebase database but somehow when image is uploaded I get a generated key Id but when I implement the delete function I no longer have access to the key therefore it's not possible to delete the image. Here is how the code is I have 2 files from 2 different folders.
folder A have the file ProfileLogo
and in there I have the component that define the uploader function to firebase code bellow.

```
   export async function UploadImageCompForPhotoLinks (image, userId, newDataRef)  {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(image);
      const blob = await response.blob();
  
      // Upload image to Firebase Storage
      const storageRef = storage.ref();
      //const userUnique = user;
      const picturesRef = storageRef.child(`GaleryPictures/PicNodes/${userId}`);
      const imageRef = picturesRef.child(`image_${Date.now()}.jpg`)
      await picturesRef.put(blob);
  
      // Get the download URL of the uploaded image
      const downloadUrl = await picturesRef.getDownloadURL();
  
      // Save the download URL in the Realtime Database
      const databaseRef = database.ref(`GaleryPictures/PicNodes/${userId}`)
      newDataRef = databaseRef.push()
      await newDataRef.set({ imageUrl: downloadUrl });
      const keys = newDataRef.key
      //console.log(keys)
  
      return downloadUrl, keys
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error uploading image:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

then I have the folder B which have the file PhotoLinks which implement the deletion function, code here.

```
   const ConfirmDelete = (newDataRef) => {
  try {

    const storageRef = storage.ref();
    const imageRef = storageRef.child(`GaleryPictures/PicNodes/${userId}/${newDataRef.keys}/image.jpg`);
    await imageRef.delete();

    const databaseRef = database.ref(`GaleryPictures/PicNodes/${userId}/${newDataRef.keys}`);
    await databaseRef.remove();

    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error deleting image:', error);
  }
}
```

Comment: You will need to know the full path (so including that auto-generated key) of the image you want to delete. Without that, your only option is to delete [all files in the user's folder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files).